# Google Maps API BUG - not returning locality for an specific example

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If you look for `Lluchmayor`, you can get locality, level_area1, level_area2 even postal code info...

However, if you look for `Carrer Gracia LLuchmayor`, which Google ID is `ChIJ7cmwIKu7lxIRZDgYa78v3jI` it just doesn't return any locality? But it however returns level_area 1 and 2 info.

Any idea why is this happening? Any workaround in mind?

Comment: That is a "route".  I suspect that might explain the lack of locality (it probably traverses more than one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment of @geocodezip. Have a look at the boundaries of the Lluchmayor on maps.google.com

https://maps.google.com/?q=07620+Llucmajor,+Balearic+Islands,+Spain&ftid=0x1297bb076b7563c5:0xc76e45725e237545

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot the Carrer Gracia is only partially located inside the locality Lluchmayor. In such situations when a route just overlaps, but not fully inside the locality Google omits the locality name in the response. This is intentional behavior.

Please also note that if you specify an address that is located inside the locality, you will get back a locality name in the response. For example, `Carrer Gracia 72,  LLuchmayor` returns the locality

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Carrer%20Gracia%2072%2C%20%20LLuchmayor&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The same result in Geocoder tool

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DCarrer%2520Gracia%252072%252C%2520%2520LLuchmayor

I hope this explains your doubt.